# Java loop-output fact

Tags: java

Think about the code below has a loop article.length

```
public String getArticle(){

String headline=article.getHeadline(); //getting a,b,c,d from here
System.out.println(article) 
return blabla;

 }
```

> Lets say output is like:

1-a
2-a
3-b
4-c
5-d
6-d

> What is the way of writing output like:

1-a 2-b 3-c 4-d

"I want to remove duplicate characters from a string"

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me. I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @JB Nizet  which part? I am trying to say, I dont want output twice. I want to control it like: if there is 2 "a" in output just write "a"

Comment: Whta is `article`? What is it's headline? What has `article.length` to do with the output? Where does `1-a 2-a 3-b 4-c 5-d 6-d` come from?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to count each character in a String?

- Create a map to store the character counts
- Iterate over the string
- For each character, add 1 to the current character count (or store 1 if this is the first occurrence)
- Print/use your results from the map

Edit: After reading your question again, I *now* think your want to remove duplicate characters from a string?

Comment: "I want to remove duplicate characters from a string"

Comment: Write a loop that iterates over all characters in the string, then check whether a character appeared before (probably by using a set), and write the current character to an output string only if it is not already contained in the set of characters.

Comment: I tried but I got System error, I guess I wrote smtng wrong. can you write something easy

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the first occurrence of each character in a string, you could do the following:

```
public String nubChars( String s ) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Set<Character> cs = new HashSet<Character>();
    final int length = s.length();
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        final Character c = s.charAt( i );
        if( cs.add( c ) ) {
            sb.append( c );
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When passed a string like `hello world` this method would return `helo wrd`.

Is this what you need?